# Help on finding level curves for a function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, functions, surfaces

For the function

g(x,y) = (x+y)/(x-y)

I found that the domain is all (x,y) such that x is different from y.

Then I had to find the level curves, but for c = -1, I get x = 0

But that is not a function, so what does this mean? Does it mean that the image of this function will never be minus one? But I plotted it, and the value minus one is reached, so I don't understand what happens when

(x+y) / (x-y) = -1

and I would like to know if c = -1 is a level curve or not. Thanks!

Comment: What that means is that the "level curve" is a vertical line.   No, it is not a function but there is no requirement that level curves be the graphs of functions.  A lot of the interesting situations involve level curves that are circles- qlso not functions.

Comment: And when $c = 1$, you have line $y = 0$ as the level curve.

Comment: Level curves are rarely functions. For a simple example consider a topographical map and note that none of the level curves pass the vertical line test.

Comment: Oh!!! Okay, I get it. Thanks for the clarification!